# How can I model a one(zero) to many relationship between two tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have table A and B that are defined like this.:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    AId int NOT NULL IDENTITY ( 1,1 ),
    Message VARCHAR(50) NULL,
)


CREATE TABLE B (
    BId int NOT NULL IDENTITY ( 1,1 ),
    Message VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    MessageLevel int NOT NULL,
    MessageDescription int NOT NULL,
)



ALTER TABLE B
ADD CONSTRAINT AK1Message_MessageContent UNIQUE
(Message);
```

Table B categorizes the message attribute that is stored in A. I would like to link tables A and B on the Message column. However all of the different messages cannot be known beforehand therefore message of record in A might not be present in B. This prevents me to use one-to-many relationship between B and A. It could be dscribed as one(zero) to many relationship between B and A.

Basically when new message type of message comes to A it is not yet categorized in table B and only after it is evaluated a record is created in table B.

Is there a way to model this relationship in sql?

I tried to use the foreign key with the NOCHECK option

```
ALTER TABLE A WITH NOCHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT FKDataMessage$HasCategorized$Message
FOREIGN KEY (Message)
REFERENCES B(Message)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

but this then produces error when inserting new records into A.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
message of record in A might not be present in B
```

And therefore you cannot have message in A be a FK pointing to B.

But you can easily have a relation from B to A, if A.Message always is present.

Comment: I cannot have a relationship from B to A. A.Message is not unique and there are multiple records of the same message. B.Message is an alternate key of the table.

Comment: There is no unique constraint I could create for A.Message.